# Does XOR work in trigger and check-constraints in oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, triggers

I am trying to find out if its possible to use XOR in trigger and check-constraints. I've seen implementation in PL/SQL, but haven't quite figgured it out if its possible to use the XOR function in trigger and check-constraints.
I tried to use it in a check-constraint:

```
 CREATE TABLE my_table
 (
    tableid          NUMBER  PRIMARY KEY,
    foreignkey1      NUMBER,
    foreignkey2      NUMBER,
    CONSTRAINT check_anleger CHECK( XOR( foreignkey1 IS NULL, foreignkey2 IS NULL));
 );
```

but unfortunately it didn't work (got a "missing right parenthesis"-Exception, which got only resolved when I deleted the constraint-command).

Does the XOR-function work in triggers and check-constraints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle Database (as opposed to PL/SQL) does not have the Boolean data type to begin with, so it doesn't support logical functions like XOR. Which means you can't use it in a constraint. But you **can** rewrite the condition, just use standard `and`, `or`, `not`, and parentheses. Triggers are (mostly) PL/SQL, so XOR should be available. However, if you can do something with a constraint instead of a trigger, that is almost always a much better option, even if the code is more cumbersome.

Comment: Thanks! But how does a check-constraint work then when it's not using the boolean data type?

Comment: SQL uses implicit boolean values, but does not have a boolean data type. See the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/datatypes.htm#LNPLS348

Comment: @watchme - the same way as "conditions" work in all of Oracle SQL. Oracle has logical "conditions" but they can't be used as "expressions" - you can't have a column of data type Boolean, or "logical", or "condition". An annoying distinction in Oracle SQL (and as I understand it, in most commercial SQL implementations). The SQL Standard, which no one seems to implement fully, requires support for Boolean data type.